# Update duplicates with distinct id number

Tags: c#, string

I have a **.csv** file. `Column1, column2, column3` define the *key combination*.

```
Row    column1      column2       column3  
1      A            120           Hdr  
2      A            120           Line  
3      A            120           Line  
4      B            130           Hdr
```

Whenever the key combination *repeats*, the repeated row should look like below:

```
3    A      120/1       Line
```

If it repeats again, the `/1` should be incremented to `/2`, `/3` and so on for upcoming rows. How should i achieve this using c#?

Comment: in this format the question is too broad. Please show the code that you use to read the file, extract the data and how you represent/store the data, and preferably a first attempt to solve this problem on your own. From this point on we can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Providing that you have a *simple* CSV (no *quotations*) you can try `GroupBy`:

```
 // Csv separator; it seems that you use `\t`
 char sep = '\t';

 var result = File
   .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.csv")
 //.Skip(1) // if you want to get rid of columns' captions
   .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {sep}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   .GroupBy(items => new {
      key1 = items[1],
      key2 = items[2],
      key3 = items[3], })
   .SelectMany(chunk => chunk
      .Select((items, index) => index == 0
         ? string.Join(sep.ToString(), items)
         : string.Join(sep.ToString(), 
                             items[0], 
                             items[1], 
                           $"{items[2]}/{index}", 
                             string.Join(sep.ToString(), items.Skip(3)))));
```

**Demo:** let's have test as `string text`:

```
string text =
@"1      A            120           Hdr  
2      A            120           Line
3      A            120           Line
4      B            130           Hdr  ";
```

And instead of `File.ReadLines` we split `text` into lines:

```
char sep = ' ';

var result = text
        .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {sep},
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .GroupBy(items => new {
          key1 = items[1],
          key2 = items[2],
          key3 = items[3], })
       .SelectMany(chunk => chunk
          .Select((items, index) => index == 0
             ? string.Join(sep.ToString(), items)
             : string.Join(sep.ToString(), 
                 items[0], 
                 items[1], 
               $"{items[2]}/{index}", 
                 string.Join(sep.ToString(), items.Skip(3)))));

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
1 A 120 Hdr
2 A 120 Line
3 A 120/1 Line
4 B 130 Hdr
```

Comment: My only comment is that you are parsing a tsv file :) perhaps '\t' should be a parameter :) Other than that, exactly my train of thought, quicker fingers

Comment: @Alexandru Clonțea: Agree, thank you! I've edited the answer